# Proving that a complex function with constant module at boundary has a zero. (EDITED)

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomrphic non-constant function in $\Omega$, and a disc $C$, such that $\overline{C} \subset \Omega$.

I want to proove that if $|f|$ is constant at $\partial C$, then $f$ has at least a zero in $C$.

Really do not know where to start.

Appreciate any help.

(From here I edited it)

So, this is what I thought.

Lets suppose that $f$ has no zeros in $\overline{C}$, then $1/f$ is holomorphic at $\overline{C}$. Since $|f|=M$ is constant at $\partial C$ and we know that a holomorphic function in a close bounded set takes its maximum in the boundary, we know that for every $z\in \overline{C}$ we have $|f(z) \leq M$ and $|1/f(z)| \leq 1/M$ so we know that for every $z \in \overline{C}$ $f(z)=M$. Then $f$ its constant in $C$.

Using maximum modulus principle we have that f must be constant in $\Omega$ (absurd).

Then $f$ must have zeros in $\overline{C}$, if they are in the boundary then using that its maximum must be in the boundary, we have that $f=0$ in $C$, and then we have the same reasoning.

Finally, $f$ must have zeros at $C$.

Comment: Isn't $C=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z|<1\}$ and $f(z)=e^z$ a counterexample?

Comment: No, because 1 and $i$ are both in $\partial C$, but $|e^1|=e$ and $|e^i|=1$, hence the module of exp is not constant at $ \partial C$

Comment: Yes, you are right! somehow i thougt about $e^{it}$

Comment: @BajoFondo Have you considered applying the maximum modulus principle to both $f$ and $1/f$?

Comment: @Kenny Wong: Okay I think I thought of something: I do not know why but i am not quite sure about this: (Its posted on top)

Comment: @BajoFondo Yeah, that's more or less the idea! :)

Comment: @Kenny Wong: Thanks, it helped a lot. Needed that kickstarter, to see where I needed to go.

Comment: You need to assume $\Omega$ is connected.